# Add subtitle to VideoJS via String

Tags: javascript, video.js, subtitle

I have a string like this

```
var subtitle = `WEBVTT

00:01.000 --> 00:04.000
- Never drink liquid nitrogen.

00:05.000 --> 00:09.000
- It will perforate your stomach.
- You could die.`
```

Now i want to dynamically load it to VideoJS from that variable without request to WebVTT file.

How to do this or it impossible? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it as a data uri:

```js
player.addRemoteTextTrack({
  src: `data:text/vtt;base64,${btoa(subtitle)}`,
  kind: 'subtitles',
  srclang: 'en'
});
```

Or parse the string and add each cue:

```js
const track = player.addTextTrack('subtitles', 'English', 'en');
const parser = new WebVTT.Parser(window, WebVTT.StringDecoder());
parser.oncue = function(cue) {
  track.addCue(cue);
};
parser.parse(subtitle);
parser.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but it will show that uri in Network panel (Devtools) and can easy to download. Do you have another way?

Comment: I used the second solution of parsing the string and it worked perfectly. The only thing is that I needed to call this code inside the ready method of the player to work: 
`player.ready(function() { ... });`